# How do I change the label back color (there are many labels) from dice roll results?

Tags: vb.net, label, vb.net-2010

Hopefully this will make sense, but I am creating this 'board' type game where there is a die and twenty-eight labels, which I have made the labels into small squares and next to each other.

I need to figure out code which will automatically light up (change the BackColor) of the labels, based on the number generated by the die, which the player clicks on.

For example, when the player clicks the die a number is generated (1 - 6) and this is how many labels light up, and continues till all labels BackColor has changed to a different colour, e.g. green.

Code for die:

```
 Private Sub imgDie_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles imgDie.Click

    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Dice, AudioPlayMode.Background)

    randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 7)

    If randomNumber = 1 Then
        imgDie.Image = My.Resources.Die_One
    ElseIf randomNumber = 2 Then
        imgDie.Image = My.Resources.Die_Two
    ElseIf randomNumber = 3 Then
        imgDie.Image = My.Resources.Die_Three
    ElseIf randomNumber = 4 Then
        imgDie.Image = My.Resources.Die_Four
    ElseIf randomNumber = 5 Then
        imgDie.Image = My.Resources.Die_Five
    ElseIf randomNumber = 6 Then
        imgDie.Image = My.Resources.Die_Six
    End If

End Sub
```

So, what could I do to make sure the correct number of labels BackColor are changed? Would I need a function? Also, as the die is clicked numerous amount of times, labels are going to light up, so how do I get it so that those that haven't changed, are until all twenty-eight labels BackColor has changed?

I hope that this makes some sense?

The labels are named:

```
lblSquareOne, lblSquareTwo, lblSquareThree right through to lblSquareTwentyeight
```

Comment: You should really learn to use GDI+

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795253/visual-basic-2010-creating-a-control-array - basically **the *first* step is to getting the collection of labels into a collection that can be *iterated/accessed-by-index* (vs. name)**. This will make it easy to find out which are "lit" and to light the next controls are required. I am not sure if the older Control Array approach is supported at all, but a collection (e.g. List) can be used, and each control added to said collection. Failing to use such a pattern results in explicit code for each control-by-name .. which does not scale.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have made a start, I think, by creating a label array?

Comment: @KSR5 As long as you can access the labels as a collection, that's a start - I haven't used VB(.NET) in years, so that post hints that such Control Arrays are deprecated (at the least). However, the same can be established manually using a `Dim Labels as List(of Label)` member (I use C#, so the syntax may be off a bit). And then populating the collection with the appropriate labels in the Form Load event.

Comment: @KSR5 Then, to toggle on N labels, loop over the collection with a counter of the number to "turn on". Each time you find an "off" label, turn it on and decrement the counter. Stop iterating when the counter reaches 0 or there are no more controls. Put that logic in a subroutine, such as `Sub TurnOnSomeLabels(n Int)`. Then you can call it from the die-roll function: `TurnOnSomeLabels(randomNumber)`. For the basic case you can use the control background to determine if a particular label is "on" or "off", but later you may want to separate out the model from the view.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it! I will try and do what you said and hope that I can make it work - as still new to it all and thought VB would be a good language to start learning with. :)

Comment: @KSR5 VB(.NET) is a decent language. It can be roughly thought of as C# with a different syntax these days ;-) I prefer C#, but I suppose that is largely due to familiarity at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might get you started:

```
Private Function ToggleLabels(ByVal NumberToDo As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim R As New Random
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim lbl As Label

    ' in MY app, the labels would all be grouped (ALONE) on a panel
    ' so I could find them easily in its Controls Array
    ' I am also using the Label.Tag property to track it's state
    '   could also go by its BackColor

    ' do until we match the die count passed OR
    ' the new AllLitUp function tells us we are Done
    Do Until (count = NumberToDo) 
        n = R.Next(0, 28)                       ' maxValue is exclusive

        lbl = LabelsPanel.Controls(n)

        ' is this one already Lit?
        If lbl.Tag = "FALSE" Then

            ' change the color
            lbl.BackColor = TheLitColor
            lbl.Tag = "TRUE"                    ' set indicator
            count += 1                          ' increase the count for this round

            ' dont need this here AND in the loop control
            If AllLitUp() Then                   ' check for game over
                Exit Do
            End If

        End If
    Loop

   ' Return T/F is it Game Over
   Return AllLitUp()
End Function
```

When you loop thru the labels to reset the color for a new game, be sure to set `.Tag` to "FALSE" (with the quotes).

Better would be LabelItem class which holds a reference to a label (which it could get itself when New) and a flag.

Then another class - LabelItems - to manage them.  LabelItems could store 28 of them in a List(Of LabelItem).  This would make managing individual labels easy (no need to loop thru an array) as well as 'global' things like a procedures to clear for a new game, get the score so far, add a Timer either for scoring or for Beat The Clock etc.

Comment: Bit of a late reply, but I was just wondering, instead of changing a random label's BackColor (n = R.Next(0, 28)), how could I get it so it went in order of which the labels are stored in the array? E.g. lblSquareOne, lblSquareTwo etc. Hope this makes sense and thank you for helping me so much :)

Comment: That it a little trickier and hard to describe options in 500 chars.  First, the Labels will built and added to `form.pnlLabels.Controls` array by the designer code so the order which may or may not have anything to do with their name (`labelOne...`).  To be certain of their order, remove the labels from the designer and create them at runtime.  `Dim lbl AS New Label ... myFrm.pnlLabels.Controls.Add(lbl)...`.  I would also use the List(Of ListItem) and make it part of her job.  Now, the first List item would be linked to the first label.  Just find the first Unlit lbl and start there in loop